# Exception being swallowed after transaction rollback on WAS + Spring + Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere, logback

Scenario: Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE; Hibernate 4.2.1.Final; WAS 8.5.5.5

When a database operation causes a violation exception (e.g.: value too long for a column), an UnsupportedOperationException is being thrown during the commit:

```
WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.setRollbackOnly(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:139)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.markRollbackOnly(CMTTransaction.java:131)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:306)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.setRollbackOnly(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:116)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter$1.invoke(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:176)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy872.beforeCompletion(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.jtaextensions.SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.java:66)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredSyncs.coreDistributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:291)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:153)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:2384)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:588)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1029)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:963)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowCommit(UOWManagerImpl.java:807)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:881)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(UOWManagerImpl.java:782)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:818)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:370)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:298)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy783.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:685)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:623)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:591)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1134)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
```

I've found a reported issue similar to the scenario above, but no one replied or presented a solution https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10388

What I'd like is to log the cause exception, indicating what the problem is, which in this case is a violation exception.

I've tried to change the log levels of both Spring and Hibernate from ERROR to DEBUG, but still, no useful information is being logged. I've done that by changing the log settings in the application and in WAS too.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which logging framework are you using and the code from where you are logging ...please provide more information

Comment: When you are doing transactional work any database operations that are invalid will do not actually go to the database until the transaction is committed.  So it is expected that exceptions do not surface until a commit/rollback is performed.  How is the exception being swallowed?  From the Hibernate link you posted it sounds like the UnsupportedOperationException is exactly what Hibernate is throwing, so I don't see any exceptions being swallowed here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the swallowed exception, because even if you have access to it, you'l still get a JTA layer error.

From Hibernate `WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform` class javadoc:

> JTA platform implementation intended for use with WebSphere
>   Application Server (WAS). WAS, unlike every other app server on the
>   planet, does not allow direct access to the JTS TransactionManager.
>   Instead, for common transaction-related tasks users must utilize a
>   proprietary API known as ExtendedJTATransaction. Even more
>   unfortunate, the exact TransactionManagerLookup to use inside of WAS
>   is highly dependent upon
>
> - WAS version
> - the WAS container in which Hibernate will be utilized
>
> This class is reported to work on WAS version 6 in any of the standard
>   J2EE/JEE component containers.

You are using WAS 8, so maybe `UnsupportedOperationException` is the correct one.