# Spring Service not rolling back the transaction after exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JpaRepository for CRUD implementation in one of my App screens. As a part of that, I am developing a feature where user can save all Car entities or nothing (should roll back) into database. I am not sure how do I achieve this functionality using Spring Boot, Spring Rest, Spring Jpa.

Below is my source code.

```
@Repository
interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> { }

@Service
class CarService {

    @Autowired
    CarRepository repo;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=RuntimeException.class)
    public List<Car> saveAllOrNone(List<Car> cars) {
        for(Car car: cars) {
            repo.save(car);
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out what wrong I am doing.

When I tested it using two different data among which 1 have invalid data, the other record is getting inserted into database instead of being rolled back.

In addition to this, I am getting an Exception like 
`UOWManager transaction processing failed:nested exception is com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: javax.transaction.RollbackException`

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Does the rollback is not working? What happens instead?

Comment: Yeah, it is not rolling back the successful entities.

Comment: The rollback only occurs when there is some error inside the transaction. Is the error occur when you persist the cars?

Comment: yeah, I have tested it purposely using invalid data like First name set to null.

Comment: Try to use `repo.save(cars)`, without the iterator. Also, try to add the `@EnableTransactionManagement` on your Application.

Comment: should I add the annotation on Repository or Service ?

Comment: add together with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Oh my god, it worked like anything, i am really thankful to you Dherik,

Comment: Can you please make a moment to explain me what was the wrong I did.

Comment: I will explain in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though its late, I would like to post the answer because someone would find this useful. I fixed the error by implementing a JPA Transaction Manager in my spring boot application using the resource [here](http://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the @Transactional is not working for you. I could understand that there is some configuration in your application that could be the responsible to not create the `DataSourceTransactionManager`. As explained here, this should be automatically:

> Spring Boot will detect spring-jdbc on the classpath and h2 and will
>   create a DataSource and a JdbcTemplate for you automatically. Because
>   such infrastructure is now available and you have no dedicated
>   configuration, a DataSourceTransactionManager will also be created for
>   you: this is the component that intercepts the @Transactional
>   annotated method

So I see two alternatives to resolve your problem.

The first is use the `save` method from Spring Repository that could accept your car list:

```
repo.save(cars);
```

This will work because the Spring has an internal @Transactional for the repository methods.

The another alternative is add together with your `@SpringBootApplication` the annotation `@EnableTransactionManagement`, enabling manually what Spring should do for you.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724100/enabletransactionmanagement-in-spring-boot).

Comment: I have also tried removing the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation on `@SpringBootApplication`, it worked. So, i should have not iterated it explicitly using For each loop. Thanks a lot Dherik.

Comment: oh no, the roll back is happening as expected, but, the exception is appearing again and again, i tried removing the `@Transactional` annotation on the Service method, then its throwing Exception like `Exception caught from before_synchronization operation: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Stacktrace is:  `Exception caught from before_synchronization operation: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at org.hibernate.engine.transation.jta.platform.internal.WebsphereJtaExtendedPlatform.TransactionManagerAdaptor.setRollBackOnly`

Comment: @DilipKumar i think that your problem is with the WebSphere: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38173907/2387977

Comment: I am not getting the details give in the post but, Is this error something that is expected or to be ignored?

Comment: Hi Dillip, I can't say exactly. But seems that could be ignored.

Comment: I have fixed the Websphere error by referring to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388069/unexpected-unsupportedoperationexception-on-hibernate-validation-failure). Now, the above error does not appear but still, the roll back is not happening for me.